# Can smoothing a histogram be considerd a kind of kernel density estimation?

Tags: density-function, kernel-smoothing, moving-average, density-estimation

Let's say that I would like to estimate a PDF of a random variable, and I obtained the histogram with 1000 bin. Subsequently, I smoothed the histogrm with a moving average filter of 5 taps. Is this similar to any type of kernel estimation?

Comment: yes...this would be a kernel density estimator where you first binned your data

Comment: @CliffAB, Thanks for the reply. Are you aware of any formal term that describes this type of kernel estimation? Appreciated your help.

Comment: not aware of anything formal. The thing is that a histogram is already a smoothing method. So the idea of smoothing a smoother is a bit odd.